# How to load an image from flash library?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I am developing an ad which involved zooming effects on mouse hover. Currently its loading an external image which placed in the same folder.

What I am looking for: I need to load the image from my same flash library. Can any one quickly help me in this ?

Comment: sorry - too lazy to provide full answer ;) try googling "flash load from library" or look at http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/as3link/

Answer (score 1):

In ActionScript, the Loader class is a DisplayObject, so you can perform the following:

```
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("path/to/image.format");
imageLoader.load(image);
addChild(imageLoader);
imageLoader.x = 200;
imageLoader.y = 300;
```

Take note that you would need to import your appropriate classes (refer to AS3 docs and look-up the classes mentioned above and use the respective import statements) and that the path passed to the URLRequest constructor is relative to your exported .swf file and NOT to your source folder.

Good luck!

Comment: user wants to load from library, not disk

Comment: Oh my how silly of me. I can't believe I misinterpreted that! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load something from library, but you can create instance of object from flash Library. You must in library set the Class field in properties of image in library. 
Example: Class - Test

in code create instance of this image

```
var Example:Class = getDefinitionByName("Test") as Class;
var image:BitmapData = new Example();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a graphic lib, you have to do things like that:

1) Create (or use existing) .fla, open it in Flash CS.

2) Import your picture to it (use File - Import - Import to stage);

3) In your image's propeties choose ActionScript tab and select "Export for ActionScript" and "Export in frame 1". Set name to your image (in my example i set it to "myImage") and set BaseClass to flash.display.BitmapData.

4) Save your .fla and publish it as .swc (you have to choose this foram in File - Publish settings).

5) Include .swc in your project (the way to do this depends on what IDE do you use).

6) Voila, you have access to any image in lib, using code like this:

```
var img:BitmapData = new myImage();
```

*If you use Flash CS to write code, you can call your bitmap even withou creating .swc, so you can ignore steps 4 and 5. Just import image and set it's AS3 linkage.